# OS X installing pecl_http

Tags: php, apache, macos, pecl

I'm trying to install php HTTP extension but I'm getting the following error during installation :

checking for magic.h... not found
configure: error: could not find magic.h

Has anyone had a similar experience ?

I'm on a MBP running 10.6.5 & php 5.3.3.

Thanks

Comment: please mark an answer as such

Answer (score 2):

```
CFLAGS="-arch i386" ./pecl install
```

or

```
sudo CFLAGS="-arch i386" /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/pecl install pecl_http
```

See: [OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) – using MAMP/PECL to install PHP extensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20120203232940/http://www.vayanis.com/2010/05/19/os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-using-mamppecl-to-install-php-extensions)

Answer (score 2):

To install the pecl_http extension on Mac OS 10.8 (using MAMP):

1. Install [brew](http://brew.sh/)
2. Install autoconf using brew `brew install autoconf`
3. Download the source code for PHP 5.4.10 (or whatever version you are using) from [php.net](http://www.php.net/)
4. Extract the source code into /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include
5. Rename the extracted file from "php-5.4.10" to "php"
6. Run ./configure in the newly created "php" folder
7. Add extension=http.so to my php.ini file
8. Restart MAMP

After that I was able to install Pecl extensions without any problems.